# Issue with .attr("href") ! An easy way to solve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
   
<head>   
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#pickhour').change(function(){
    pickhour1 = $(this).val();
    $("#link1").attr("href", "http://lezkrlzekrzlmrez/" + pickhour1 + "/rzerzetztzerze/");
  });
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
 
<select id="pickhour" name="pickhour">
   <option value="1">1H</option>
   <option value="2" selected>2H</option>
   <option value="3">3H</option>
   <option value="4">4H</option>
  </select> 
      
  <a href="" id="link1">That link</a>
 
</body>
```

Hi everyone, my problem today is that .attr which dont apply on my . I want the href of "link1" update dynamically with the change of select option in "pickhour". I tried many things but Im not really smart with JS, I hope somebody will understand whats wrong, it seem to be so easy.. BUT ITS NOT ! ><

Comment: Maybe cuz the problem come from my script ?

Comment: But there is no Java code here.

Comment: I tested it and it works fine

Comment: Maybe OP confused Java and JS @immibis

Comment: code snippet it.. --'

Comment: It dont work at all for me, please show me what you did

Comment: Did you forget to include jQuery in your page?

Comment: Maybe that's it, because it works with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/4x6sn50c/1/

Comment: It seem :O But there still something wrong.. Same with jquery 2.1

Answer (score 2):

Add to your `<HEAD>`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You forgot the ending `</script>`

Comment: You need to add it as an extension - not as link: http://jsfiddle.net/4x6sn50c/1/ @JoelFan's answer is correct.

Comment: Sorry but what is the difference on my website ? I added `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in my `<HEAD>`, my code still didnt work :s

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="buybtn"> 
                      <select id="pickhour" name="pickhour">
          <option value="1">1H</option>
          <option value="2" selected>2H</option>
          <option value="3">3H</option>
        <option value="4">4H</option>
          </select> 
                       </div>
                       <div id="buybtn2">
                         <a id="egglink" >Reserver un cours</a>
                       </div>

 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#pickhour').change(function(){
    pickhour1 = $(this).val();
 $("#egglink").attr("href", "http://school.egg-one.com/private-lesson/program-choice/program_choice/" + pickhour1 + "/player_id/87946");
      });
       }); 
                </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: omg, it work on code snippet.. My jquery loading is wrong i guess.

Comment: Its exactly like that in my code but it still dont work

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but no more ideas ? :S

Comment: Maybe calling the divs buybtn2 and buybtn in a jquery cause that?

Comment: I copied the code above to my machine, and it is working fine (Chrome 40)

Comment: Maybe it's some browser issue... I notice you are missing <html> ... </html> tags around your whole code

Comment: also you should add `type="text/javascript"` to both your `<script>` tags.  Also you should add `var` before `pickhour1 = .... `.   But none of these should stop it from working